# Regex Exlude a String if Followed by a Particular String

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have seen some answers here and tried to implement them unsuccessfully.

Basically, I want  to include `@generated`. However, if '@generated' is followed by 'NOT', such as `@generated NOT`, then I would want to exclude that.

Here is my attempt: `^/(?!NOT)(@generated)$`

I tested this on regex pal and it does not work. Furthermore, I cannot find a pattern that works reliably. For instance, I don't want to accidentally tag `NOT` when `@generated` does not precede it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the below regex,

```
@generated(?!\s*NOT)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tI1dR9)

It would match the word `@generated` which is not followed by zero or more  `spaces` and the string `NOT`.